# admob of google play service does not showing over surfaceview

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, google-play-services, surfaceview

I have an android game that draws on a surfaceView and I have admob ads on top of that using a FrameLayout.
    FrameLayout lay = new FrameLayout(this);
        this.addContentView(lay, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

```
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxx");
    lay.addView(renderer, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    lay.addView(adView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    adView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    this.setContentView(lay);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

and everything is fine. I want to integrate the new google play services admob and I have changed the above code to

```
FrameLayout lay = new FrameLayout(this);
    this.addContentView(lay, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("xxxxxxx");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    lay.addView(adView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    this.setContentView(lay);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

the admob view is not shown up. I know that it is the view that does not come up because if i add only the AdView into the frameLayour then I see the ads without any problem

Has anyone came across this problem? Has anyone any suggestion about that?

king regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you set a background color for the adview. It can be "transparent". Then, using a RelativeLayout or a FrameLayout as your parent layout, define the layout parameters for the adView to be positioned, for example at the bottom center of the screen like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
        adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); 
        // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
        // until the ad is loaded.
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        // Create an ad request.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        //Request full screen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        //Create a displayMetrics object to get pixel width and height
        metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        width = metrics.widthPixels;
        height = metrics.heightPixels;


     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        layout.addView(renderer);
        layout.addView(adView, adParams);

        //Set main renderer             
        setContentView(layout);

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot when I set a color everything is fine. I assume its a "hack" but I do not mind.